# Syntax error trying to use CGRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to add a subview to a tableview cell and of course using CGRect as part of that. However, I get a syntax error on build:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 1:
            CGRect <<- SYNTAX ERROR cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 65);
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            CGRect infoRect = CGRectMake(0, 5, 295, 55);
            UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoRect];
            infoLabel.tag = 1;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:infoLabel];
            [infoLabel release];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

I have tried right-clicking on Frameworks -> add existing framework and that does not appear to help. I guess it seems like the compiler is still not seeing the framework?

Edit: in fact, I just noticed CoreGraphics.framework was in fact already loaded into the project. So I'm really confused now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare `cellFrame` outside of the `switch` statement:

`CGRect cellFrame;

switch (indexPath.section) {

case 1:

cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 65);

break;

...

}`

or put brackets around it:

`switch (indexPath.section) {

case 1:

{ CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 65);  }

break;

...

}`